# Python Potato Cannon

Tags: python, python-3.x, physics

Could someone tell me why the result for height is always 0.00m / -0.00m?

What did I do wrong?

```
import math

g = 9.8
v = 60

angle = float(input("Angle: "))

def distance(v, angle, g):

    angle2 = angle * 2
    d = v**2 * math.sin(math.radians(angle2))/g
    return d

distance = distance(v, angle, g)

def time(distance, v, angle):

    t = distance/(v * math.cos(math.radians(angle)))
    return t

time = time(distance, v, angle)

def height(v, angle, time, g):

    h = v * math.sin(math.radians(angle)) * time - g * time**2/2
    return h

height = height(v, angle, time, g)

print("""Time: {0:.2f}s
Distance: {1:.2f}m
Height: {2:.2f}m""" .format(time, distance, height))
```

Comment: Is this Python 2 or Python 3?

Comment: This is for Python 3

Comment: What are you trying to calculate specifically? Your distance is the full distance travelled during the trajectory, so as pointed out by @Ewan, your height will always be zero at the two possible solutions, t=0, h=0, or t=X, h=0 (at D=distance). Did you want this, or you wanted the peak height, time of flight of the trajectory, and range?

Answer (score 1):

You're computing the height of the cannonball (or whatever it is) at the time that it returns to the ground.  Which is always zero.

You want to pass `time / 2` into the height calculation (since you're ignoring air resistance here).

Comment: The first part is right, but I don't understand your second point. Firstly, air resistance is velocity dependent (usually), and is an extra term in the equation. If you ignore the air resistance, then it's just not included in the equation. The height is still -1/2at^2. Can you elaborate on your thoughts?

Comment: @jonnybazookatone The path is a downward pointing parabola on a graph of H vs T.  At T=0 and T=time we know H=0.

Comment: @Paul. Yes, that's why I understood the first point. I was asking why he wanted to modify the equation to `time / 2`, it should remain `g * time^2 / 2`. And why there was any mention of air resistance? In the current context this doesn't make sense without an explanation. Plus where do you get downards pointing, you can specify the angle yourself?

Comment: @jonnybazookatone I didn't say "change the equation", I said "pass time/2 into the height calculation" i.e. `height = height(v, angle, time / 2, g)`.  Sorry if that wasn't clear the first time.  You know that "maximum height" is at `total-time / 2` as long as you are ignoring air resistance (and the curve of the Earth) because the flight path is a parabola so it is symmetrical by construction.  This isn't necessarily true in the general case (imagine if the cannonball had a parachute attached to it) so you can't take that shortcut.

Comment: Incidentally, this question, and the code, will all be a lot easier to understand if there weren't all those name clashes between the functions, the parameters inside the functions, the variables outside the functions, and the global constants.  I'd rename everything for clarity before I went any further working on this code.  There's also no need to have a global constant like `g` and then pass it explicitly into the function too.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification @EwanMellor, could you update the answer to include your some of your comments? I had already made assumptions about this being in a vacuum, so your comments on no air resistance made me confused. Also, your last comment is also useful, I'd put that in the OP rather than your answer.

Answer (score -2):

Try adding these parentheses:

```
h = v * math.sin(math.radians(angle)) * (time - g) * time**2/2
```

Comment: An explanation why these parentheses make a difference would be helpful.

Comment: What kind of a quantity is `(time - g)`?